# Allow users to restat programs on terminal server

Tags: terminal, powershell, terminal-server

Our TS is locked down so people can't even get onto task manager to restart a process that is hanging.
I don't want to compromise the security of the TS but I would like to give users the ability to close certain programs when they hang?

I also wouldn't mind creating a PowerShell script to restart process that hang but not sure how successful that will be.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me so I don't have to log onto the TS everyone a process hangs.

Comment: I'm sorry, this question is off topic, it's either too broad or too opinion based :( My thoughts are, if it's not happening often, ask IT to do it (who can have the raised privileges). Otherwise, work out why it's hanging and solve it.

Comment: How is that even "opinion based"?

Comment: Try this just need to modify registry value
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/37417-autoendtask-apps-not-responding-shutdown-windows.html

Comment: It sounds like you are IT 'cus you have to log in to the TS when this happens.  I do agree with Dave that you should figure out what the problem is rather than working around it unless you need a quick fix.  This is sounds like a "problem" and the underlying issue should be addressed.  Is there a specific program that hangs or is it programs in general?